# Wake ESP8266 based MCU on contact close/open

Tags: esp8266

I am trying to build what I thought was a relatively simple system (think deadbolt detector), that will fire an event when a simple switch changes state.

Currently, I am testing with an ESP-01 and an ESP32, using deep sleep but the power consumption still seems quite high, because I have to wake the device up every 10 seconds to query the status of the "switch".

I would like to only wake from sleep when the state changes, I can "easily" do this on "close", but I would like to do this on "open" as well like in this question.
[I need a switch that not only detects open/close, but also sends a pulse to wake up an ESP8266 whenever the (debounced) state changes](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/286191/i-need-a-switch-that-not-only-detects-open-close-but-also-sends-a-pulse-to-wake)

I have read up on XOR/XNOR gates, but I am still not sure, how I would implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Perhaps you could use a Schmitt trigger EXOR as specified [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/394089/convert-a-toggle-switch-into-a-momentary-response).** 
[image]

*Source: [Convert a toggle switch into a momentary response](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/394089/convert-a-toggle-switch-into-a-momentary-response)*

It will create a momentary high pulse whenever a regular toggle switch (deadbolt) is switch on->off or off->on. You could then wire that ouput to an external wakeup pin for said microcontroller.

As you are specifying multiple microcontrollers I suggest that you look up the external wakeup procedures for the board you are using. Many examples are available such as [this one](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/ESP32/examples/DeepSleep/ExternalWakeUp/ExternalWakeUp.ino) for the ESP32.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

This is a working prototype that I made. You can see more details about parts, modify and order your own if you want.

This is the schematic:
[image: schematic]

Here is a link to my project on jlcpcb:
https://easyeda.com/jakibsgaard/low-powered-rising-and-falling-power-on-circuit

I have also a open question where I want to improve the circuit I have made. But that is not required. This has much more information about the circuit I made. [Improving edge detector with latching circuit for esp8266](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/519758/improving-edge-detector-with-latching-circuit-for-esp8266)

Comment: Your good, there really isn't a question, the first time I looked at it I thought there was.